# Response headers overridden when sending binary data

Tags: php, http-headers, zend-framework2, mp3

**The background of the problem**
I'm using jPlayer to play some audio files in a ZF2 application. jPlayer uses a ZF2 action as the audio source which works fine. From the controller action I send back a raw response using a Response object. The simplified code looks like this:

```
public function streamAction()
{
    // ... left out code to retrieve order and error handling stuff ... //
    $response = $this->getResponse();
    $path = $this->orderService->getFullPathToAudioFile($order);
    $response->setStatusCode(Response::STATUS_CODE_200);
    $response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Content-Type', 'audio/mpeg')
                            ->addHeaderLine('Content-Length', filesize($path))
                            ->addHeaderLine('Expires', -1)
                            ->addHeaderLine('Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');

    $response->setContent(readfile($path));

    return $response;
}
```

In Chrome jPlayer's HTML5 implementation had no problem using this as the source of the audio. Firefox automatically fell back on the Flash implementation of jPlayer and also works fine. Safari also uses the HTML5 implementation but has a problem with this, but works fine when I use the Flash implementation of jPlayer.

This triggered me to look into what headers are actually being sent back in the response. I used Firebug to check this. I noticed something strange here: the Content-Length header was not being sent back and the Content-Type is 'text/html' and not 'audio/mpeg' as I specified.

**Test code**
I made a little testAction to demonstrate:

```
public function testAction()
{
    $path = './data/audio/test.mp3';

    $response = $this->getResponse();
    $response->setStatusCode(Response::STATUS_CODE_200);

    $response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Content-Type', 'audio/mpeg')
                           ->addHeaderLine('Content-Length', filesize($path))
                           ->addHeaderLine('Expires', -1)
                           ->addHeaderLine('Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');

    $response->setContent(readfile($path));

    return $response;
}
```

**Please note**
I verified the audio file can be found. I can also see this as I call the test action in my browser. It shows the contents of the mp3 file.

**The plot thickens**
When I comment the line setting the content: $response->setContent(readfile($path));
I do see the correct Content-Type header and Content-Length header in the response.

Also when I create a simple plain text response like below it also works correctly.

```
public function testAction()
{
    $response = $this->getResponse();
    $response->setStatusCode(Response::STATUS_CODE_200);

    $response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
                           ->addHeaderLine('Content-Length', 10)
                           ->addHeaderLine('Expires', -1)
                           ->addHeaderLine('Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');

    $response->setContent('0123456789');

    return $response;
}
```

Any ideas why this is and better yet how I can fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue with your code is that `readfile()` does not *return* the file contents, it outputs them to the browser immediately. So changes you make to the response object have no effect as the response object isn't used. If you change this to `file_get_contents()` it'll probably work as you expect.

Unless the files you're streaming are tiny (<10KB), I'd recommend you look into XSendFile, which will do all of this in a much more memory efficient way, and also automatically handle the headers for you (including range headers, which will let people skip through the track).

Comment: Awesome, that was the whole issue. Thanks a lot!